# About quartz jdbcjobstore

Tags: exception, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to use quartz cluster, run the same program on different machines.
But get

```
org.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: Unable to store Job with name: 'fecheJob' and group: 'group2', because one already exists with this identification.
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1075)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$3.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:1024)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$39.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3639)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3711)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.executeInLock(JobStoreTX.java:93)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3635)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJobAndTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1012)
```

Is there apis that I can check if this job store name already exist ?
Thank you

Comment: i believe you can find this using `scheduler.getJobDetail(arg0)` and `scheduler.getTrigger(arg0)`